# How to use tf.keras Sequential with tf.distribute.ParameterServerStrategy and tf.train.MonitoredSession?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I'm trying to set up a really easy Minimal Working Example for the following: Use a model built with tf.keras in a tf.train.MonitoredSession using a tf.Server with a tf.distribute.ParameterServerStrategy.

My goal in the end is to use a tf.keras model in a distributed environment using two workers each having one GPU and a parameter server.

The model is built according to the example and documentation found here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.12/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/Sequential

The parameter server strategy is used according to the documentation found here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.12/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/distribute/ParameterServerStrategy

The overall setup including the device placement and the use of a MonitoredSession is taken from: https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/community/en/docs/deploy/distributed.md

I'm already using the "allow_soft_placement" option and I'm "emulating" a distributed setup on my local machine having only a single CPU, since there are different problems in the real distributed setup which I'm trying to solve by using a MonitoredSession where the variable initialization is handled automatically.

This Code works with a "normal" (not monitored) tf.Session and variable initialization - global, local, model variables and tables etc.

The line which unfreezes the graph is necessary to be able to use a tf.data.Dataset in the tf.keras.Model's fit function, since an iterator has to be created - which causes an error in a frozen graph.

This the code I'm trying to run. I use tensorflow 1.12.0 and python 3.6.7. I've also tried python 2.7, same result.

The code requires no setup besides installing tensorflow.

```py
import sys
import tensorflow as tf

def main(argv):

  # Create local cluster config for run_local_server.sh script.
  cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"worker": ["localhost:2222"], "ps": ["localhost:2223"]})
  task = 0
  job = str(argv[0])

  # Number of GPUs per worker
  GPU_PER_WORKER = 0

  config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=False)
  server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name=job, task_index=task,config=config)

  strategy = tf.contrib.distribute.ParameterServerStrategy(num_gpus_per_worker=GPU_PER_WORKER)
  strategy.configure(session_config=config, cluster_spec=cluster,task_type=job,task_id=task)

  with strategy.scope():
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

    x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255
    x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255

    # Reshape input data from (28, 28) to (28, 28, 1)
    w, h = 28, 28
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], w, h, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], w, h, 1)

    # One-hot encode the labels
    y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
    y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

    train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_train),tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y_train))).repeat().shuffle(60000).batch(10)
    val_ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_test),tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y_test))).repeat().shuffle(10000).batch(10)

    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % task,cluster=cluster)):
      model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

      conv0 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, data_format='channels_last', padding="valid", kernel_size=4, strides=1, input_shape=(28,28,1), activation=tf.keras.activations.relu)
      model.add(conv0)

      flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
      model.add(flatten)

      dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax)
      model.add(dense1)

      model.compile(tf.contrib.optimizer_v2.AdamOptimizer(0.001), loss=tf.keras.metrics.mean_absolute_error,metrics=['accuracy'],distribute=strategy)   

    if job == "ps":
      server.join()
    elif job == "worker":
      with tf.train.MonitoredSession(session_creator=tf.train.ChiefSessionCreator(master=server.target,config=config)) as sess:        
        sess.graph._unsafe_unfinalize()
        history = model.fit(x=train_ds, validation_data=val_ds, validation_steps=1000, steps_per_epoch=100, epochs=60)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main(sys.argv[1:])
```

The code requires no extensive setup since the dataset is loaded from the web and converted to a tf.data.Dataset since this is how I want to organize my pipeline with the real data. The MNIST data setup example is taken from 
https://www.kaggle.com/margaretmz/mnist-with-tf-keras.

I expect the code to not fail due to wrong variable or operation placement since I'm basically leaving all these decisions to the implementation of tensorflow by using `strategy.scope()` and `tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % task,cluster=cluster))`

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I switched to non-distributed training and the tf.Estimator API.

Comment: The best I could find is tf.data and keras.model.fit is the preferred way of doing things.

Comment: Well this is how it's done in the script ... a tf.data Dataset and the last line of main function is model.fit(...).